# Use PSFTP on Linux

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp

I am using Linux Suse 10 and I am a complete noob when it comes to using it that's why I really needed some help.

The scenario is simple. I need to transfer some files from my linux server to a windows pc.

I already did this using FTP commands written inside a .scr file. Here's the content of my Upload.scr :

```
ftp -n 10.*.*.* <<SCRIPT
user administrator drowssap
cd TESTDIR
binary
lcd /path/of/the/txt/file/
put TESTUpload.txt
bye
SCRIPT
```

And then I would call it from linux Konsole using :
bash Upload.scr

It was actually working and could successfully transfer files to my windows pc. However, what I need is to transfer the files using "psftp".

The original code which works from windows-to-windows transfer is :

```
ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C psftp " + UserName + "@" + IP + " -pw " + Password + " -b UpLoad.scr");
```

I needed to do the same to my linux-to-windows transfer (i.e. I needed to use psftp instead of just ftp or sftp).

Whenever I tried to type "psftp" on linux Konsole it would display the ff :
**bash: psftp: command not found**

I know there's something missing. What should I do first to make it work? Should I install some application or .exe file into my linux server?

I really need help.
Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psftp` is PuTTY's `SFTP` utility.

OpenSSH has one too, named simply `sftp` (without the `p`). It is very likely already installed on your Linux machine.

If you want to install PuTTY's `psftp`, you just need to run:

```
apt-get install putty-tools
```

or equivalent for your distribution.

Comment: Thank you!

So you're saying that I may use just plain "sftp" and create the script on my Upload.scr?

Uhm, before I can transfer files through sftp, I would also need an sftp server waiting on my windows pc right? Do I need to install something to have an sftp server on it?

So sorry for all the questions and confusions and thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, you need an sftp server. AFAIK, Microsoft doesn't provide one. You'll need to search for it. Yes, you just use `sftp` as you would `psftp`. Please read the man page.

Comment: That enlightens me. Thank you so much.